# Кеширование списка md-autocomplete

Tags: angularjs

Разбираюсь с директивой autocomplete, код честно спёр с какого-то примера и чуть переработал под себя.

HTML

```
<md-autocomplete
        ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled"
        md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
        md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
        md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
        md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
        md-items="item in querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
        md-item-text="item.display"
        md-min-length="3"
        placeholder="Введите имя сервера">
    <md-item-template>
        <span>{{item}}</span>
    </md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>
        Сервер "{{ctrl.searchText}}" не найден.
    </md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

JS

```
var api = $resource('/api/');
$scope.querySearch = function (search) {
    var query = api.get({m:'searchServer',search:search});
    return query.$promise.then(function (data){
        return data.r;
    });
}
```

Суть проблемы.

Допустим я вбиваю в поиск `serv` - происходит запрос, возвращается список, например:

```
serverA
serverB
serverC
```

Понятно, что этот список содержит все элементы, которые будут соответствовать более точному имени (`serve`,`server`,`serverA`,...) и делать новый запрос на каждый новый введенный символ мне нафик не нужно.

Вопрос: Есть ли у этой директивы **штатные** возможности включения... как бы его назвать... "упреждающего" кеширования? Что бы если был сделан запрос по строке, то дальше значения читались из уже загруженного списка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Штатных средств не нашел. Реализовал кеширование таким образом:

```
$scope.cacheKeyLength = 3;
$scope.cache       = [];

var api = $resource('/api/');
$scope.querySearch = function (search) {
    var prefix = search.substr(0, $scope.cacheKeyLength);
    if($scope.cache[prefix] !== undefined){
        return filterList($scope.cache[prefix], search);
    }
    var query = api.get({m:'searchServer',search:search});
    return query.$promise.then(function (data){
        $scope.cache[prefix] = data.r;
        return data.r;
    });
}

filterList = function (search, array) {
    return array.filter(function (element) {
        return element.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1
    });
};
```